# How do I convert strings from csv in d3.js and be able to use them as a dataset?

Tags: csv, d3.js, dataset

Sorry if this seems obvious, I'm new to D3 and computer programming in general...
I have a `CSV` file that has number values, but when they show up as strings in my console.

I tried putting the `parseFloat` function in my code, but then the data shows up as `NaN` on my console for each entry.

This is my code:

```
var dataset =d3.csv("file.csv", function(d){return{data: parseFloat(d)}; },
 function(data){    
 console.log(data);     
 });
```

My data looks like this in one column from my csv file:

```
9.96E-001
9.95E-001
9.95E-001
9.95E-001
9.96E-001
9.95E-001
9.96E-001
9.94E-001
9.96E-001
9.95E-001
9.94E-001
9.96E-001
1.00E+000
```

Obviously I do need to make them have integer values to then get them to work as a `dataset`, but I can't even get them to have number values instead of strings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

javascript should be able to understand numbers formatted like that if you cast them as numbers:

```
var dataset = d3.csv("file.csv", function(data){
  data.forEach(function(d){ d['columnName'] = +d['columnName']; });   
  console.log(data);     
});
```

where `'columnName'` refers to the title of the column with the the numbers.

If that doesn't work, try posting your csv so we can see if something else is going wrong.

Comment: Yes! That made the data appear as my numbers in my console, which was what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: Is there no automatic way of trying to do what is best with d3?