# What is the equivalent to forEach in D3 v7?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to find the equivalent to the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17601105/how-do-i-convert-strings-from-csv-in-d3-js-and-be-able-to-use-them-as-a-dataset) for D3 v7 so I can have D3 read a column as numeric instead of a string.

Here's the code in the link:

```
var dataset = d3.csv("file.csv", function(data){
  data.forEach(function(d){ d['columnName'] = +d['columnName']; });   
  console.log(data);     
});
```

I also tried `data.row(function(d)...` but also received an error.

Comment: d3.csv changed in d3v5, now you use `d3.csv("url").then(function(data) { ... })`.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49604124/7106086)